# Is there a nice way to make function signatures more informative in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, coding-style, functional-programming

I realize that this could potentially be considered a subjective or maybe an off-topic question, so I hope that rather than have it closed it would get migrated, maybe to Programmers.

I'm starting to learn Haskell, mostly for my own edification, and I like a lot of the ideas and principles backing the language.  I became fascinated with functional languages after taking a language theory class where we played around with Lisp, and I had been hearing a lot of good things about how productive Haskell could be, so I figured I'd investigate it myself.  So far, I like the language, except for one thing that I can't just get away from: Those mother effing function signatures.

My professional background is mostly doing OO, especially in Java.  Most of the places that I've worked for have hammered in a lot of the standard modern dogmas; Agile, Clean Code, TDD, etc.  After a few years of working this way, It has definitely become my comfort zone; especially the idea that "good" code should be self documenting.  I've become used to working in an IDE, where long and verbose method names with very descriptive signatures are a non-issue with intelligent auto completion and a huge array of analytical tools for navigating packages and symbols; if I can hit Ctrl+Space in Eclipse, then deduce what a method is doing from looking at its name and the locally scoped variables associated with its arguments instead of pulling up the JavaDocs, I'm as happy as a pig in poop.

This is, decidedly, not part of the community best practices in Haskell.  I've read through plenty of different opinions on the matter, and I understand that the Haskell community considers its succinctness to be a "pro".  I've gone through [How To Read Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_read_Haskell#General_advice), and I understand the rationale behind a lot of the decisions, but it doesn't mean that I like them; one letter variable names, etc. aren't fun for me.  I acknowledge that I'll have to get used to that if I want to keep hacking with the language.

But I can't get over the function signatures.  Take this example, as pulled from [Learn you a Haskell[...]](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)'s section on function syntax:

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> String  
bmiTell weight height  
    | weight / height ^ 2 <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"  
    | weight / height ^ 2 <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"  
    | weight / height ^ 2 <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
    | otherwise                   = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

I realize that this is a silly example that was only created for the purpose of explaining guards and class constraints, but if you were to examine *just* the signature of that function, you would have no idea which of its arguments was intended to be the weight or the height.  Even if you were to use `Float` or `Double` instead of any type, it would still not be immediately discernible.

At first, I thought I would be cute and clever and brilliant and try to spoof it using longer type variable names with multiple class constraints:

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height) => weight -> height -> String
```

This spat out an error (as an aside, if anyone can explain the error to me, I'd be grateful):

```
Could not deduce (height ~ weight)
    from the context (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height)
      bound by the type signature for
                 bmiTell :: (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height) =>
                            weight -> height -> String
      at example.hs:(25,1)-(27,27)
      `height' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for
                 bmiTell :: (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height) =>
                            weight -> height -> String
               at example.hs:25:1
      `weight' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for
                 bmiTell :: (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height) =>
                            weight -> height -> String
               at example.hs:25:1
    In the first argument of `(^)', namely `height'
    In the second argument of `(/)', namely `height ^ 2'
    In the first argument of `(<=)', namely `weight / height ^ 2'
```

Not understanding completely why that didn't work, I started Googling around, and I even found this little post that suggests named parameters, specifically, [spoofing named parameters via `newtype`](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/09/keyword-arguments-in-haskell/), but that seems to be a bit much.

Is there no acceptable way to craft informative function signatures?  Is "The Haskell Way" simply to Haddock the crap out of everything?

Comment: For your aside, the ~ means "equals" at the type level, so the error is saying that height and weight is not the same type, and the division operator requires its operands to be of the same type.

Comment: @hzap that makes perfect sense.  Thanks.

Comment: The more I use Haskell, the more I appreciate the "spoofing named parameters via `newtype`" approach.  Especially for this sort of `width/height` problem.  It keeps code clear and more maintainable and strongly aids in dimensional analysis.  If you do it right the boilerplate is minimal, type signatures are more useful, and bugs are less frequent.

Comment: You could just go the TypeFamilies way and add type equality to your constraints. I don't think this way is necessary, or clearer, but you _could_. `(RealFloat weight, weight ~ height) => ...`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A type signature is not a Java-style signature. A Java-style signature will tell you which parameter is the weight and which is the height only because it mingles the parameter names with the parameter types. Haskell can't do this as a general rule, because functions are defined using pattern matching and multiple equations, as in:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
map _ [] = []
```

Here the first parameter is named `f` in the first equation and `_` (which pretty much means "unnamed") in the second. The second parameter doesn't *have* a name in either equation; in the first parts of it have names (and the programmer will probably think of it as "the xs list"), while in the second it's a completely literal expression.

And then there's point-free definitions like:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = foldr (++) []
```

The type signature tells us it takes an parameter which is of type `[[a]]`, but no name for this parameter appears **anywhere** in the system.

Outside an individual equation for a function, the names it uses to refer to its arguments are irrelevant anyway **except** as documentation. Since the idea of a "canonical name" for a function's parameter isn't well defined in Haskell, the place for the information "the first parameter of `bmiTell` represents weight while the second represents height" is in documentation, not in the type signature.

I agree absolutely that what a function does should be crystal clear from the "public" information available about it. In Java, that is the function's name, and the parameter types and names. If (as is common) the user will need more information than that, you add it in the documentation. In Haskell the public information about a function is the function's name and the parameter types. If the user will need more information than that, you add it in the documentation. Note IDEs for Haskell such as Leksah will easily show you Haddock comments.

---

Note that the preferred thing to do in a language with a strong and expressive type system like Haskell's is often to try make as many errors as possible detectable as type errors. Thus, a function like `bmiTell` immediately sets off warning signs to me, for the following reasons:

1. It takes two parameters of the same type representing different things
2. It will do the wrong thing if passed parameters in the wrong order
3. The two types don't have a natural position (as the two `[a]` arguments to `++` do)

One thing that is often done to increase type safety is indeed to make newtypes, as in the link that you found. I don't really think of this as having much to do with named parameter passing, more that it is about making a datatype that explicitly represents **height**, rather than any other quantity you might want to measure with a number. So I *wouldn't* have the newtype values appearing only at the call; I would be using the newtype value wherever I got the height data *from* as well, and passing it around as height data rather than as a number, so that I get the type-safety (and documentation) benefit everywhere. I would only unwrap the value into a raw number when I need to pass it to something that operates on numbers and not on height (such as the arithmetic operations inside `bmiTell`).

Note that this has no runtime overhead; newtypes are represented identically to the data "inside" the newtype wrapper, so the wrap/unwrap operations are no-ops on the underlying representation and are simply removed during compilation. It adds only extra characters in the source code, but those characters are *exactly* the documentation you're seeking, with the added benefit of being enforced by the compiler; Java-style signatures tell you which parameter is weight and which is height, but the compiler still won't be able to tell if you accidentally passed them the wrong way around!

Comment: +1 for excellent explanation - why we can't do it Java's way, why type safety is the way to go - readability as a side effect of the far more important correctness - Doug's worried he might not be sure which way round, Ben says make the compiler enforce the right way round. Excellent.

Comment: +1 because when I learned Haskell in uni, I hated it - but I not only understood and _enjoyed_ your explanation, I actually felt myself loving Haskell for a moment.

Comment: @Ben At first I was hesitant about the `newtype` trick as I had said above, but seeing your rationale for it not only making the signature verbose but also introducing an additional level of type-safety seems like a good argument, and one that I like. I'm still adjusting to the conciseness of the language. One of the tenets at the lab where I work is that code should be so English-like that any random line out of context should be understandable by a non coder, and that readable is more important than correct. I have to acknowledge that I'll never have that level of verbosity in Haskell.

Comment: @DougStephen: Speaking as a programmer in industry who's used C# for years, had a limited academic background, and learned Haskell for fun in his free time--those are utterly, mind-bogglingly *terrible* guidelines for practical coding in too many ways for me list in a comment. Making code read like English? *Really?* Haven't we learned *anything* from prior mistakes?

Comment: @C.A.McCann I don't know that I'd say they are terrible guidelines.  It's all part of the ideology behind refactoring, TDD, clean code, etc.  Complicated code can be refactored out in to a method with a descriptive name, things like that.  There has to be some complexity, you just push it down as low in the abstraction as possible. I also work in an industry (robotics) where most of the programmers aren't actually programmers by trade, only out of necessity. So readability is important.

Comment: @DougStephen: Yes, and the fundamental mistake in such guidelines is thinking that they actually make the code easier to understand in a meaningful way. They don't. English is not precise enough to describe non-trivial code anyway, and longer names have higher cognitive load when reading the code. Not to mention that a 90% complete description is often more misleading than a 10% one, because it's much harder to notice that it's doing more than what it claims to. I'm sorry, but they really are terrible.

Comment: @C.A.McCann I've personally never found that to be the case, but then again I'm most likely working on a fundamentally different problem domain from the one that you're working on. As guidelines they have served us very well and kept us productive so we feel no need to get rid of them. But I also understand why they don't necessarily have a place in Haskell and that fighting the semantics of the language won't do me any good.

Comment: @DougStephen: I'm speaking more of C# than of Haskell here, and from the perspective of "mundane" industry coding that involves a lot of UI and data manipulation logic, informed by various code bases I've worked on over the years. Haskell code, as you've probably noticed, often errs in other directions. :]

Comment: Best answer I've seen written for a while. +1 rep.

Answer (score 36):

There are other options, depending on how silly and/or pedantic you want to get with your types.

For example, you *could* do this...

```
type Meaning a b = a

bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a `Meaning` weight -> a `Meaning` height -> String  
bmiTell weight height = -- etc.
```

...but that's incredibly silly, potentially confusing, and doesn't help in most cases. The same goes for this, which additionally requires using language extensions:

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height, weight ~ height) 
        => weight -> height -> String  
bmiTell weight height = -- etc.
```

Slightly more sensible would be this:

```
type Weight a = a
type Height a = a

bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => Weight a -> Height a -> String  
bmiTell weight height = -- etc.
```

...but that's still kinda goofy and tends to get lost when GHC expands type synonyms.

The real problem here is that you're attaching additional semantic content to different values of the same polymorphic type, which is going against the grain of the language itself and, as such, usually not idiomatic.

One option, of course, is to just deal with uninformative type variables. But that's not very satisfying if there's a significant distinction between two things of the same type that's not obvious from the order they're given in.

What I'd recommend you try, instead, is using `newtype` wrappers to specify semantics:

```
newtype Weight a = Weight { getWeight :: a }
newtype Height a = Height { getHeight :: a }

bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => Weight a -> Height a -> String  
bmiTell (Weight weight) (Height height)
```

Doing this is nowhere near as common as deserves to be, I think. It's a bit of extra typing (ha, ha) but not only does it make your type signatures more informative even with type synonyms expanded, it lets the type checker catch if you mistakenly use a weight as a height, or such. With the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension you can even get automatic instances even for type classes that can't normally be derived.

Comment: I was with you until you turned on `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.  Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @JohnL: Not a fan of that extension, I take it? For `newtype`s used as glorified type synonyms it seems reasonable to me...

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't mix it with GADTs or TypeFamilies, I think GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving is fine.

Comment: @ErikHesselink : Could you explain or point me to a resource that explains why it's bad to use newtypes with GADTs or Type Families?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I plug my own blog: http://joyoftypes.blogspot.com/2012/08/generalizednewtypederiving-is.html

Comment: mix it with meaning "use it with in complicated ways" not simply "use it in the presence of" one should note.

Comment: Yes, I mainly thought of [the bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1496) also linked to in that blog post.

Comment: @C.A.McCann - I use that extension too, and like it in principle.  Just snark, apologies!

Comment: @JohnL: No worries. I knew dodgy stuff was possible with it, but not the extent demonstrated in Philip JF's link. I'm happy to throw that extension into the same level of Hell as `OverlappingInstances`, both being (of course) one level worse than mere `UndecidableInstances`... ;]

Comment: @C.A.McCann Indeed, `OverlappingInstances` can lead to pain.  Out of curiosity, where do you consign `IncoherentInstances`?

Comment: I think that the newtype should not be "Weight", but a proper unit, say "kg". That way you know exactly what it is supposed to contain, what you get when you combine it with other units and you can naturally add a Distance and a Length. It may sound like nitpicking, but think of something like a "sleep (Time a)". Is Time in minutes,  seconds or something else?

Comment: @JohnL: If one were to assign each extension a value from 0 to 1, such that 1 is purely benevolent and 0 is utterly malevolent, `IncoherentInstances` would be located at roughly -0.28+0.96i.

Answer (score 26):

Haddocks and/or also looking at the function equation (the names you bound things to) are the ways that I tell what's going on.  You can Haddock individual parameters, like so,

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a      -- ^ your weight
                         -> a      -- ^ your height
                         -> String -- ^ what I'd think about that
```

so it's not just a blob of text explaining all the stuff.

The reason your cute type variables didn't work is that your function is:

```
(RealFloat a) => a -> a -> String
```

But your attempted change:

```
(RealFloat weight, RealFloat height) => weight -> height -> String
```

is equivalent to this:

```
(RealFloat a, RealFloat b) => a -> b -> String
```

So, in this type signature you have said that the first two arguments have *different* types, but GHC has determined that (based on your use) they must have the *same* type.  So it complains that it cannot determine that `weight` and `height` are the same type, even though they must be (that is, your proposed type signature is not strict enough and would allow invalid uses of the function).

Comment: Gotcha. I think my brain is still working on separating the ideas of types and types classes. But that makes sense now that I see it put that way.

Comment: +1 for [Haddock individual parameters](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s02.html#id565220). Though I would still recommend the `newtype` approach.

Answer (score 13):

`weight` has to be the same type as `height` because you're dividing them (no implicit casts). `weight ~ height` means they're the same type. ghc has gone on a bit explaining how it came to the conclusion that `weight ~ height` was necessary, sorry. You are allowed to tell it what it/you wanted to using syntax from the type families extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
bmiTell :: (RealFloat weight, RealFloat height,weight~height) => weight -> height -> String
bmiTell weight height  
  | weight / height ^ 2 <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"  
  | weight / height ^ 2 <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"  
  | weight / height ^ 2 <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
  | otherwise                   = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

However, this isn't ideal either. You have to bear in mind that Haskell uses a *very* different paradigm indeed, and you have to be careful not to turn up assuming that what was important in another language is important here. You are learning most when you're outside your comfort zone. It's like someone from London turning up in Toronto and complaining the city is confusing because all the streets are the same, while someone from Toronto might claim London is confusing because there is no regularity in the streets. What you're calling obfuscation is called clarity by Haskellers.

If you want to return to more object-oriented clarity of purpose, then make bmiTell work just on people, so

```
data Person = Person {name :: String, weight :: Float, height :: Float}
bmiOffence :: Person -> String
bmiOffence p
  | weight p / height p ^ 2 <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"  
  | weight p / height p ^ 2 <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"  
  | weight p / height p ^ 2 <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
  | otherwise                   = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

This, I believe, is the sort of way you would make this clear in OOP. I really don't believe you're using the type of your OOP method arguments to obtain this information, you must be secretly using the parameter names for clarity rather than the types, and it's hardly fair to expect haskell to tell you the parameter names when you ruled out reading the parameter names in your question.[see * below] The type system in Haskell is remarkably flexible and very powerful, please don't give up on it just because it's initially alienating for you.

If you really want the types to tell you, we can do that for you:

```
type Weight = Float -- a type synonym - Float and Weight are exactly the same type, but human-readably different
type Height = Float

bmiClear :: Weight -> Height -> String
....
```

That's the approach used with Strings that represent filenames, so we define

```
type FilePath = String
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()  -- take the path, the contents, and make an IO operation
```

which gives the clarity you were after.  However it's felt that

```
type FilePath = String
```

lacks type safety, and that

```
newtype FilePath = FilePath String
```

or something even smarter would be a much better idea. See Ben's answer for very important point about type safety.

[*] OK, you can do :t in ghci and get the type signature without the parameter name, but ghci is for interactive development of the source code. Your library or module shouldn't stay undocumented and hacky, you should use the incredibly lightweight syntax haddock documentation system and install haddock locally. A more legitimate version of your complaint would be that there isn't a :v command that prints the source code for your function bmiTell. Metrics suggest that your Haskell code for the same problem will be shorter by a factor (I find about 10 in my case compared to equivalent OO or non-oo imperative code), so showing the definition inside gchi is often sensible. We should submit a feature request.

Comment: Upvoted because the `Person` record is the better approach, IMHO. Even if you've introduced newtypes to distinguish height from weight, Alice's weight divided by Richard's height isn't a BMI.

Comment: Thanks @Zopa for your edit/correct. I reinstated it after someone strangely rejected it.

Comment: I like your explanation, but feel that "the better approach" would be to have the record _and_ the `newtype` - that way, you both 1) Associate the weight/height for the same person; 2) Use the type system to ensure that you're using a weight and a height, and not just two arbitrary Floating/RealFloat-type numbers.

Comment: @BMeph I agree. The OP led me to believe `newtype` wasn't wanted, and I should have stated their case, but Ben did so excellently. His is a great answer - upvote it if you haven't! Yes, record type + newtype is good. MathematicalOrchid makes a good point about long lists of arguments too. Lots of good answers here I think.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
type Height a = a
type Weight a = a

bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => Weight a -> Height a -> String
```

Answer (score 12):

Possibly not relevant to a function with a piffling two arguments, *however*... If you have a function that takes lots and lots of arguments, of similar types or just of unclear ordering, it may be worth defining a data structure which represents them. For example,

```
data Body a = Body {weight, height :: a}

bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => Body a -> String
```

You may now write either

```
bmiTell (Body {weight = 5, height = 2})
```

or

```
bmiTell (Body {height = 2, weight = 5})
```

and it will worth correctly both ways, and also be damed obvious to anybody trying to read your code.

It's probably more worth it for functions with a larger number of arguments, though. For just two, I would go with everybody else and just `newtype` it so the type signature documents the correct parameter order and you get a compile-time error if you mix them up.

Comment: ...so the individual parameters have names, visible under :i in ghci. Tick. You could even make some of them Maybe if you miss optional parameters.